# Confusion about Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some confusion about ElasticSearch's Index.

In some place I read it's the equivalent of rdbms' database and some other place, an Index is like what we have at the end of books : list of words with corresponding documents that contain the word.

If someone can clarify.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An Elasticsearch cluster can contain multiple **Indices** (databases). These indices hold multiple Documents (rows), and each document has Properties or field(columns).
you can check list of your available indices with http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v .

but in general (computer sciences and DB) indexing means like you said.

> list of words with corresponding documents that contain the word

. this structure improves the speed of data retrieval operations on a database table. this concept could be used in many DB like mysql or oracle. in elasticsearch by default all document will be indexed. (you can change this settings to not indexing some columns/fields)